# Relaunch program in VS 2010 debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, process

I have an application that occasionally requires you to restart it after changing preferences.  I do this by calling:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
```

That's great for the released version, but it's really annoying when I'm debugging and it relaunches the program outside the debugger whenever I need to change the preferences.

After some research, I've tried attaching to the debugger from code, but the very code I'm trying to run is running in the debugger already, and the application will be killed shortly.  So I wrote an external program that can be called after relaunching the application (and freeing up the debugger) that supposedly attaches it to the debugger.  Unfortunately this doesn't really do the job either.  It appears to get attached to the debugger, but it doesn't actually let me do any debugging.  It just craps out with an error if I try to pause execution.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use the windows utility gflags to set the OS to launch your application under the VS2012 debugger. gflags is found in Microsoft's free windows debug SDK. When you are not debugging, you simply run gflags and turn off the automatic launch of Visual Studio loading up and debugging your application.

Comment: Thanks.  Looking at it now.

Comment: The Visual Studio 2010 just in time debugger is named: vsjitdebugger.exe. So you will need to have gflags invoke vsjitdebugger.exe "yourappname.exe". That should start a new instance of the debugger, but I don't think it will have any break points set. The Visual Studio site has instructions on manually setting the registry at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a329t4ed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx (GFlags sets the registry for you, which is why I mentioned it).

Comment: Does that mean it will launch a new instance of Visual Studio?  I'm trying to replicate the behavior of basically hitting the restart button from code.

Comment: Yeah, it will. I don't know of any other way to get Visual Studio to reload your app automatically for you and restart when the code being debugged exits (ie, changes preferences, starts a new invocation of itself, and exits).

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to attach to the debugger? I suspect you may not be using the right `Process` object (should be `Process2`) and `Attach` method (should be `Attach2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, I realized all I wanted to do was programmatically hit the Restart button. I found this:

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
dte.ExecuteCommand("Debug.Restart");
```

Works great!

Comment: Good that you found the solution but 30 mins between question and answer?

Comment: Sometimes posting the question makes you think of things you didn't think of before.  But thank you for implying what you're implying.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to debug with your code if you are using a `Process` object and its `Attach` method from the `EnvDTE` namespace rather than the `Process2` object and its `Attach2` method from the `EnvDTE80` namespace. The following snippet should work:

```
foreach (Process2 process in Dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses) {
   if (process.ProcessID == processId) {
       process.Attach2();
       Dte.Debugger.CurrentProcess = process;
   }
}
```

May also be of interest here: the Visual Studio team has released a Visual Studio extension that allows automatically attaching child processes to the current debugger: [Introducing the Child Process Debugging Power Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool.aspx).

It is available on the [Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1141bff-463f-465f-9b6d-d29b7b503d7a) for Visual Studio 2013 and above.